# Mult-byte chars get displayed with single-byte encoding

Tags: javascript, node.js, character-encoding, putty

Here's my code:

```
console.log('\u00A9');
```

My console output (from node.js) is:

```
Â©
```

How do I get rid of that Â character?

[image]

Comment: UTF-8 works fine for me on Windows Vista. What's your shell and/or operating system?

Comment: Windows 8.1 PuTTY'ing into a Debian x64 system

Comment: I guess this does not have to do with node, it has to do with your shell/console being capable of rendering extended ASCII characters.

Comment: Ah I just changed PuTTY's translation settings to be UTF-8 and it is healed now. Can anyone tell me why it wasn't working before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PuTTY configuration, please have a look at Window→Translation. You probably have the default value at "Character set translation on received data", which is ISO-8859-1 or a similar single-byte encoding. You need to change it to UTF-8.

Comment: This fixed it. Why does ISO format show the extra A character?

Comment: The © symbol is encoded differently in ISO-8859-1 and UTF-8. It's just a coincidence than the second byte in UTF-8 looks like © when misinterpreted as ISO-8859-1.